# Prepend only new content from json feed with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm curently parsing a json feed into a div, this part is okay right now.
But each entry will have a form, and on each refresh the form is gone.

What i want is prepending only the new content IF there is new content on the json feed so i can keep the form content for each entries.

My current code:

```
$(function () {
    function reload (elem, interval) {
        var $elem = $(elem);
        var $original = $elem.html();
        $.ajax({
            cache : false,
            url : 'ajax.php',
            type : 'get',
            success : function (data) {
                var servers = JSON.parse(data);
                var res = '';
                for(var i = 0; i<servers.length; i++){
                    res = res + '<div id="' + servers[i].serverid +'" class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>' + servers[i].serverid +'</strong> ' + servers[i].servername +'<input></div>';
                }

                    $('#feed').empty().prepend(res);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    reload(elem, interval)
                }, interval);
            }
        });
    }
    reload('#feed', 5000);
});
```

Comment: `id` should be unique. `<div id="art"` use it wisely.

Comment: Are there any unique denomination that could be used ? `servers[i].serverid` or `servers[i].servername`

Comment: serverid is unique, and the div id will be this id, i should have mentioned that, my bad ;p

Comment: @JohnKonolol But you are concatening string in a loop resulting with duplicate IDs. If not, post relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the case then you can use an additional attribute named`data-serverid` or `data-somename` ,

```
<div id="something-unique" data-serverid="servers[i].serverid"></div>
```

And when you are iterating though the loop, check that value,

```
//Search Whole page for element having data-serverid="somevalue"
if($(document).find("[data-serverid='" + servers[i].serverid + "']").length==0){
   //Append that value else do nothing
}
```

And, Change it to ,

```
$('#feed').prepend(res);
```